# Want to advertise App on FB but App at risk of restriction for violation I can't fix

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-ads

I have an App registered with facebook.  The app has the SDK installed - I can verify this because dashboard shows most recent installs.  I want to advertise the App on FB using the App installs goal in Ads manager however facebook keeps flagging the app and threatening restriction.

Facebook keeps flagging the app for violating because:

***"We were not able to find any Facebook integration in this app or verify the permission use case that you provided during App Review. Please answer the questions below to help us review your use of Meta APIs."***

I revoked every permission because the app doesn't need any of those integrations right now.  Instead I ONLY want to advertise where the ads optimize for installs.  I don't need the API, I don't need user data, I only need the SDK itself installed in the App to verify installs.

Super frustrating. Anyone have experience with App Review on Facebook?

Full violation below:
*Resolve Violation
During review of apps on the platform, we found that we need you to provide or update information about this app so that we can confirm that it is following our Platform Terms and Developer Policies.
In review
A Dispute has been submitted for the Violation.
​
Platform Term 7.a
Platform Term 7.a - Provide required information
We weren't able to review your app because we are missing information required from you to complete our review. This violates Platform Term 7.a.
Platform affected:
iOS
Reason for this request
We were not able to find any Facebook integration in this app or verify the permission use case that you provided during App Review. Please answer the questions below to help us review your use of Meta APIs.*

Comment: I think its pretty obvious what I'm trying to achieve right?  I'm trying to achieve advertising for our iOS/Android App that optimizes for installs.  The app itself does not require any FB integrations *for now*.  When you say 'Facebook App' perhaps you are referring to facebook native apps like games?  This is not a 'Facebook App' - it is your standard everyday mobile app.  Also, the direction of your feedback seems entirely off - I'm not trying to use facebook to publish anything.  I'm trying to use it strictly as a marketing platform.